# Performing arithmetic on Ruby String variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a ruby string variable that can have the value `1.10.2.ab2-4.cl6` or `1.11.2.ab2-4.dl5` or `1.13.2.ab2-4.el6`

I want to take the first two integer values of this variable which could be `1.10` or `1.11` or `1.13` and then print hello if the value is `< 1.13`

Comment: Please define `< 1.13`

Comment: it means if the value is `1.10` or `1.11` but not `1.13`

Comment: What about `1.2`, is it larger or smaller than `1.13`?

Comment: _"is a higher version"_ – are these version numbers? If so, then `1.2` would come before `1.13` not afterwards. Unless you have a trailing zero as in `1.20`. Could you clarify this?

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. `1.2` would come before `1.13` not afterwards. `2.0` will be a higher version. I am going to delete the previous comment

Comment: Since your question is tagged `rubygems` – are your strings version strings of Ruby gems?

Comment: it is not strings of Ruby gems. It is actually a regular string variable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these are *version strings*, you could use [`Gem::Version`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html) and [`Gem::Requirement`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Requirement.html):

```
requirement = Gem::Requirement.new('< 1.13')

requirement.satisfied_by? Gem::Version.new('1.10.2.ab2-4.cl6') #=> true
requirement.satisfied_by? Gem::Version.new('1.11.2.ab2-4.dl5') #=> true
requirement.satisfied_by? Gem::Version.new('1.13.2.ab2-4.el6') #=> false
```